# PHP Beginner - What am i doing wrong?

Tags: php

First of all, im a beginner so please excuse me if i don't mention things that could be important.

I have Sellers, that are in different countries in the world. Each country belong to a continent. 
**Im trying to:**

- get the seller name
- Fetch Database to see in what countries (China,Italy,Germany...) he offers his goods.
- Then fetch another database and see in what continents (ASIA,EU) belong each country
- Store the countries (Italy,Germany) to a variable $country_eu and $country_asia (China). So later i will add this variables to update database fields.

if($continent == 'ASIA') is not included in the code YET since i take one by one the steps. I want to make first EU work, then i figure out the rest.

```
include_once('../db.php');

session_start();

$seller_name = $_SESSION['seller_name'];
echo $seller_name;

  if (!empty($_POST['flag_image'])){
    $flags_array = $_POST['flag_image'];
    $flags_string = implode(",",$flags_array);
  }else{
     $flags_string = '';
  }

$cont_eu = '';

   // Assign Flags to Continents
    foreach ($flags_array as $flag_image){  
     $qry_find_flag_continent = " SELECT continent FROM flags WHERE flag_image = '$flag_image' ";
     $result = $dbdetails->query($qry_find_flag_continent);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $continent = $row["continent"];


    if ($continent == 'EU') {
     $cont_eu .= $flag_image;
    }   
} 
echo $cont_eu;
```

**The problem** with my code is that when i echo $cont_eu is giving me just 1 result(Germany) and not the **EXPECTED** (Italy,Germany)

Comment: Please make the question "title" a code/issue *summary*. Reformat the loops and if blocks for legibility / properly indented if feasible.  Also what are the database contents? What are the actual input vars? Why is `flag_image` an array? Print out the result $row in between.

Comment: How many EU are in the database? Right now you are doing a check of all inside of 'continents' and you are doing an if statement checking if they are 'EU' to display. How many are EU?

Comment: print out post and flags_array before foreach. make sure you have two countries as you expect.

Comment: countries (China,Italy,Germany...) he offers his goods. So there are at least 2 EU countries.

Comment: Can you show what the contents of `$_POST['flag_image']` contains? ie: `print_r($_POST['flag_image'])`

Comment: how many continents use the same flag? :o

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your precious time and attempts to help. Here is the new code that works great.

```
include_once('../db.php');

session_start();

$seller_name = $_SESSION['seller_name'];
echo $seller_name.'<br>';

if (!empty($_POST['flag_image'])){
    $flags_array = $_POST['flag_image'];
    $flags_string = implode(",",$flags_array);
    } else {$flags_string = '';}


// Assign Flags to Continents
foreach ($flags_array as $flag_image){

$qry_find_flag_continent = " SELECT continent FROM flags WHERE flag_image = '$flag_image' ";
$result = $dbdetails->query($qry_find_flag_continent);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $continent = $row["continent"];
if($continent == 'EU'){ $eu_flags_array[] = $flag_image;}

    } 
}
print_r($eu_flags_array); //Gives me Array ( [0] => Germany.png [1] => Italy.png )
```